# Use Right Ctrl + Right Alt combination in AutoHotKey

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am trying to create three key combinations in AutoHotKey. They are

> A) Right Alt replaced by Right Click
>
> B) Right Ctrl replaced by Left Click
>
> C) Right Ctrl + Right Alt replaced by Shift + F10

The script I created is:

> RCtrl::Click Right
>
> RAlt::Click Left
>
> RCtrl&RAlt::+F10

While Line B is working correctly, A & C are having problems.

Line A is sending Ctrl+Right Click instead of Right Click Only.

Line C is giving and error.

So, please help me fixing them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A

```
RCtrl::
Keywait, Rctrl      ;wait for RCtrl to be released
Click Right
return
```

C
same way, wait for the keys to be released.

```
RCtrl & RAlt::
Keywait, Rctrl
Keywait, RAlt
Send +{F10}
return
```

Comment: Actually `U` isn't exist in options of [KeyWait](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm) command. Either: leave blank this parameter or use `L` letter.

Comment: @Grey Yes you're right . I used U all the time as it was synonymous with D and it worked that way. Will correct the answer